# Is TCP connection re-used in this scenario?

Tags: c#, http, tcp, keep-alive

In one of our Asp.Net web page we have this code:

```
//Call a Web Api, the web api is installed on a webfarm behind ACE load balencer
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress ="....";
client.GetAsync("/api/Worker");
```

Now if there are 100 simultaneous requests, do they all share the same TCP connection (considering that keep-alive is enabled on the load balancer) that gets created by the first request that gets through?

Thanks

Comment: Hm... no. Each request goes through its own pipeline. Since you're creating a new HttpClient, nothing will be shared so far.

Comment: Now that I think more about it, your comment makes sense. In general how does a server (that has keep-alive enabled) tie up different requests from same client to same TCP connection is it through client ip address & remote ephemeral port?

Comment: Once a TCP connection has been made between two endpoints, that's it. Only those two endpoints can use the connection. If a client wants to reuse a connection for multiple requests, it has to keep the connection open and reuse the exact same connection (i.e. socket). (And of course, the server has to support reuse of the connection for multiple requests).

Comment: @SriHarshaVelicheti It doesn't. Each request happens on its own. Remember: HTTP is stateless. Request comes in, response goes out, end of story, connection closed.